# Page number highlight bug when searching a tag AND a string on PC site

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was looking through the World of Warcraft questions, when I noticed a weird inconsistency with my page number.

[image: As you can see, the page number marked does not match the page number I am on. Apologies for the lack of hand-drawn circles ;)]

As you can see, I'm on page 2, but page 1 is still highlighted. I have determined that this happens when I search under a tag, having replicated the issue with the Star Wars - The Old Republic tag. If I search for [world-of-warcraft] or [swtor], there is no problem. But I can replicate the problem by searching for [[world-of-warcraft]+portal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?page=3&tab=relevance&q=[world-of-warcraft]%20portal), or [[swtor]+jedi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?page=5&tab=relevance&q=[swtor]%20jedi).

I have confirmed that this occurs across multiple computers. I do not believe the mobile site has the same interface in question, as I can not manage to display page number options, under a tag search. I have also confirmed that the problem persists across page size; Provided there are still multiple pages, this error will occur if there are 15 or 50 questions on the one page.

I can still move between each page number, but other then page 1, the previous page will always remain marked. If I go to page 3, it will highlight page 2. If I go to page 4, it will highlight page 3. This includes going to the page by clicking the number, by clicking the "next" button and by manually entering a different page number in the URL.

If I am on the very last page, it will naturally highlight the index before it. So if I am on page 4 of 4, it will highlight 3. However, I have also noticed the next button still appears, where it normally does not if I am on the last page. Clicking on the button simply reloads the page, but the inconsistency remains.

This should not be a debilitating error, in any way or form. But I noticed it, and thought I would bring it up. Probably something as mundane as mishandled index numbers.

Comment: I think unless it's specific to arqade bug reports should probably go on the meta site.

Comment: I thought so, too, @Aequitas. I had a look at questions under the bug tag, and the first few seemed to follow the same suit. [1](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10807/bold-italic-links-do-not-show-in-link-colour-on-mobile) [2](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10802/reputation-graphs-have-been-wound-backwards) [3](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10782/tag-page-says-im-on-featured-tab-but-that-tab-doesnt-exist) [4](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/getting-reputation-notification-too-late)

Comment: @Aequitas Devs track the [meta-tag:bug] tag on site specific metas. It's perfectly okay to post bug reports here. They will get more attention from *other users* at Meta.SE, which is helpful if you're interested in a workaround or having other users confirm the behavior your seeing, but in terms of getting something fixed, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting!

The search code went through some refactoring lately, and this off-by-one error crept in.

This is fixed in the next build (rev 2015.10.29.2916)